# Raspberry pi zero w with zerocam

Tags: pi-zero-w, libcamera

I am trying to take an image with the zeroca but when i use command raspi still it returns this massage "ERROR: the system should be configured for the legacy camera stack"

Comment: The error message "the system should be configured for the legacy camera stack" can be fixed by enabling the legacy camera API using rpi-config.You can find more info here:  https://techoverflow.net/2022/03/14/how-to-fix-raspistill-error-the-system-should-be-configured-for-the-legacy-camera-stack/  If the problem is not solved, you can also consider using  Raspberry pi Noir camera V2: https://www.pcbway.com/project/gifts_detail/Raspberry_Pi_NoIR_Camera_V2.html

Comment: what is your question?